# Minimum value of a Logarithmic equation

Tags: inequality, logarithms

What is the minimum value of

$$\log_a(x)+ \log_x(x) $$

where $0\leq a\leq x.$ I do not understand why my book says the answer is $2$ because  when i take $a=0.1$ say and $x =0.2$ I get $\approx 1.6$....

So is my book wrong or am i wrong?

Comment: Do you mean this $$
\log_a x + \log_x x
$$ or more interesting equation $$
\log_a x + \log_x a
$$

Comment: You should really invest in using mathjax search on meta for that (ps I am so lazy not to embed link here).

Comment: The first one chinny

Comment: Just tell me what is the answer and why

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Comment: @gammatester i have given the range already... See the qiestion we cannot take a 3 and x=0.1

Comment: @KristofferRyhl this is not my homework question

Comment: @user166748 You should still properly typeset your question. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: I suppose that there is a typo in the book. $\log_a x + \log_x x=\log_a x +1$ is really of very minor interest while $\log_a x + \log_x a$ is an interesting one for which the answer of $2$ makes some sense.

Comment: @claude in that case also the answer is - infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well
$$
\log_x(x)=1
$$
So the function is
$$
\log_a(x)+1
$$
Since $\log_a(x)$ has a limit of $-\infty$ when approaching either $0$ or $\infty$ depending on the value of $a$, there is no minimum.